# Laravel 5.1 get data from connected table

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5.1, belongs-to

In my app `admin users` can create `articles`. Articles table is: `ID | user_id | title ...`

For every `Article` other user **(which not admin)** can post an `offer` and Offer table is: `ID | user_id(not admin) | article_id | price ...`

Now I need to `get all users` for an **admin** user which post Offer to their Article... I try:

```
 public function userbase()
    {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;//get admin id
        $articles = Article::where('user_id', $id)->get();//select all admin articles
        foreach ($articles as $article) {

         $users = Offer::where('article_id', $article['id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); //get all admin users

        }


         return $users;


    }
```

but I get just: []

also my Model is:
**Article:**

```
public function offers() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

**Offer:**

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function article() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
}
```

So how I can get all user details which was posted offer to an admin user?

**UPDATE**

I also try this:

```
$articles = Article::with([
  'offers' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $query->with('user'); // if you want to eager load users for each offer too...
  }
])->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

and I get this data:https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbMqh.png

but how to access `user` data? I try `->get('user')` but dont work...

**2. UPDATE:**

I also try:

```
  public function userbase()
{
    $articles = Auth::user()->articles()->get();
    foreach ($articles as $article) {

         $offers = Offer::where('article_id', $article['id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        }
    foreach ($offers as $offer) {

         $users = User::where('id', $offer['user_id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        }

        return $users;
}
```

but I get undefined variable users

Comment: looks like a bad database design , you could create `article_has_offers` pivot table and handle it that way instead of querying if the user is admin or not.Also you should define the foreign key in relations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
First, you may add an attribute 'isAdmin' in your User model.

```
public function userbase()
{
    return Offer::select('users.*')
                ->where('users.isAdmin', false)
                ->join('articles','articles.id','=','offers.article_id')
                ->join('users','users.id','=','articles.user_id')
                ->where('articles.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->orderBy('offers.created_at', 'desc')
                ->groupBy('users.id')
                ->get(); 
}
```

Updating Your solution :

```
 public function userbase()
 {
  $articles = Auth::user()->articles;
    foreach ($articles as $article) {

     $offers = Offer::where('article_id',$article->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    }
    $users = array();
    foreach ($offers as $offer) {

     $users[] = User::where('id', $offer['user_id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    }

    return $users;
 }
```

Comment: I make admin field in users table where admin have int 1 and other user 9 but when I try your code i get: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Table 'users' inconnue (SQL: select `users`.* from `offers` inner join `articles` on `articles`.`id` = `offers`.`article_id` where `users`.`admin` = 9 and `articles`.`user_id` = 8 group by `users`.`id` order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: what's your User table name in Mysql DB

Comment: its users ... also I update question with possibl solution

Comment: hm, i get just: [] ... but there is alredy users who put offer to admin article ...

Comment: Ok I updated my answer according to your solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109386/discussion-between-bkf-and-andrew).